Is there an interest in proposing a Neuroimaging site on Area 51?
Apologies in advance if this question is more appropriate for the "meta" site.  I apparently do not yet have privileges to post there.
I was wondering if any members of this community might be interested in proposing a new StackExchange site for asking questions regarding Neuroimaging analysis.  The proposal would require a solid base of support in order to have any chance of getting off the ground.   
I use "neuroimaging" in the broadest sense possible, to include a range of diverse modalities (e.g., MRI, PET, SPECT, MEG, EEG).
Pros of a new site: 
(1) To my knowledge, no general Q&A platform exists for neuroimaging analysis; existing forums tend to focus on specific software packages.
(2) A general Neuroimaging site could be a welcoming environment for all practitioners of the relevant methods, including those who work outside of cognitive science / neuroscience / psychology (e.g., bioengineers, radiologists, computer scientists, etc). 

One of the biggest reasons. As far as I can see, that CogSci is still in Beta is that we are quite a small community. Note that CogSci is a fusion of three initial proposed sites. In all,spinning off of a dedicated neuro imaging site will not work in my opinion. Here and at Biology I encounter very little questions on imaging in the first place.

Thanks for the input.  I may try again with meta.cogsci down the road.  And, I agree that a new imaging community would struggle if you don't see frequent relevant questions here and in Biology.

I just downvoted this question, not because I dislike the question, but I argue against this idea (fyi: voting in meta is more agree/disagree than anything else).

Further, EEG is not imaging. If you wish to proceed, I urge you to think about whether to include electrophysiological techniques and what that would mean for the site's name etc.

I remember this coming up a couple of years ago. Somebody started a neuroimaging proposal and I think it was closed on A51. Pretty much everything you could ask on neuroimagining is perfectly on topic here.

@Christiaan: As an aside, EEG, especially with modern high-density systems and source reconstruction methods, is considered an imaging modality in humans. Books and method reviews on this topic are available, e.g. Michel et al. (2009): "Electrical Neuroimaging", Cambridge University Press.

I think AliceD captures the issue in his comment.

One of the biggest reasons. As far as I can see, that CogSci is still in Beta is that we are quite a small community. Note that CogSci is a fusion of three initial proposed sites. In all,spinning off of a dedicated neuro imaging site will not work in my opinion. Here and at Biology I encounter very little questions on imaging in the first place.

But more generally, neuroimaging questions are welcome on this site. So please feel welcome to ask them here.
Check out for example, some of the tags we already have:

fmri 24 questions at time of posting
neuroimaging 39 questions at time of posting
eeg 59 questions at time of posting

So feel free to post here. I don't think there's any need to fragment the community.

+1 Great answer, and I fully agree, obviously :)

AliceD and Jeromy -- Thanks again for the feedback.  I am glad that technical questions are welcome here.  That's a good start.
